# How to set unequal intervals on Y axis in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to create a chart that will have a custom tick range. Having an issue on how to set up the axis though, tried using logscale too but it didn't work properly. Any help is appreciated, attaching a pic for reference.

[How I want the axis to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ2Ty.png)

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(props.dailyDataAll, function (d) { return d.confirmed }))
        .range([height, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this really does not answer your question, but I think it may be just a common [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

As such I would suggest instead of struggling to plot ticks properly, you could simply replace `Y` values with `Math.log10(Y)` which would make ticks work exactly as you wanted (100 being 2 on the Y scale, 1000 being 3, 10000 being 4 and so on, effectively one tick per order of magnitude just like in your requirements)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried using a logscale but the graph was not quite right, it was not proportionate, I want the graph to be divided into equal areas as per the log scale.